# How can I run nodemon from within WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm, nodemon

I would like to use [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) from within the WebStorm IDE (version 7). Nodemon watches one or more files in my source folder and restarts the node process (an Express server in this case), when one of the source files changes.

How do I configure WebStorm to use *nodemon* in a *Run Configuration*, so that the node process is automatically restarted?

Without *nodemon*, I use the following configuration in WebStorm, but have to restart the node process whenever I change something in the source file:

- Node interpreter: `/usr/local/bin/node`
- Working directory: `/Users/foo/test`
- JavaScript file: `server.js`

This results in a Run Configuration that runs `node server.js` in the specified directory.

From command line, I can use the following command to use *nodemon* to watch for file changes: `nodemon server.js` in the project directory.

How do I need to change the WebStorm configuration so that it also uses *nodemon*?

Comment: This question seems to be along the same lines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175041/script-fails-in-webstorm-but-not-from-terminal?rq=1

Comment: See my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52463378/7350853 is using the most updated version of the Webstorm so far.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

It looks like the workaround with `--exec` isn't necessary anymore, at least when using the newest version of [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) and Webstorm 7 or 8.

All you have to do is specify your path to *nodemon* by obtaining its path with running `which nodemon` in your console (e.g. `/usr/local/bin/nodemon`) under "Node parameters":

[image: Webstorm with nodemon]

@Bela Clark, thanks for confirming.

---

You may NOT have `nodemon` exists from `which nodemon` command, then you should have it in your package.json ie `nodemon` be installed at `:project_dir/node_modules/.bin/nodemon`

Then from Webstorm 's run/debug config, set `Node parameters` to be

```
:path_to_project_dir/node_modules/.bin/nodemon
```

---

You should save the debug/run config to file so your teammates can also easily debug/run your nodejs app like you

[image]

This will save the config into some .xml file, sample as below

```
<component name="ProjectRunConfigurationManager">
  <configuration default="false" name="index.js" type="NodeJSConfigurationType" path-to-node="$USER_HOME$/.nvm/versions/node/v19.4.0/bin/node" nameIsGenerated="true" node-parameters="../node_modules/.bin/nodemon" path-to-js-file="index.js" working-dir="$PROJECT_DIR$/nodejs27/node27_sequelize_apiapp/src">
    <method v="2" />
  </configuration>
</component>
```

Comment: Just gave this a try - it works perfectly fine now. Thanks for providing an updated answer!

Comment: @bernhardw, webstorm doesn't stop on breakpoints when starting debugger with these configurations. Any idea why?

Comment: Managed to get nodemon and breakpoints working by following these instructions: https://vcfvct.wordpress.com/2015/02/13/debug-nodejs-with-nodemon-and-intellij/
Note that I used --debug-brk instead of --debug

Comment: To make debugging work I had to use Live Edit plugging for IntelliJ instead of nodemon.

Comment: Good answer ! Thank you

Comment: But, debugging is not working i.e program is not stopping at breakpoints. ??

Comment: to stop at breakpoints you have to put the parameter --inspect-brk in 'node parameters: ' and run in debugging mode.

Comment: Following on from iwaduarte's breakpoint fix, `--inspect-brk` has to go into Application Parameters to work, not Node Parameters (for me anyway - WebStorm 2019.1.4)

Comment: reminder: you have to physically click on the run window in order for it to update after you implement this solution

Comment: Didn't work for me at all on MacOS 13.1, node 18, nodemon 2.0.20. nodemon doesn't start with this config (which seems logical, as it is a binary in my case and works as a standalone binary and not as a node parameter - though it worked for many people somehow...). This answer helped me to start nodemon: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26345577/11575732

Answer (score 40):

**This is the Windows solution**

You can just use the nodemon.cmd instead of node directly like :

```
Node interpreter : C:\MyPath\To\nodemon.cmd
Node parameters : /*Empty for me*/
Node WorkingDirectoy : C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop\DirectoryContainingMyIndex.js
JavaScriptFile : app\index.js /*or just index.js depending on your config*/
```

and then :

[image]

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I thought this was the most straight forward answer.

Comment: Hi, Tried this and when I change a file it asks me (in the Web Storm console) "Terminate batch job (Y/N)?". I also see that the command being executed is: "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 8.0.4\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.cmd --debug-brk=27344 --nolazy -q app.js.
Am I missing anything?

Comment: for the "terminate batch job" problem just add " < nul" (leave out quotations) to the "Application parameters" input. (answer found here: http://superuser.com/a/498798)

Comment: Why is this upvoted ? It won't work, when nodemon restarts it doesn't add the " <nul" from the initial start, so you still get "Terminate batch job (Y/N)?"

Comment: the location in windows is C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.cmd

Answer (score 20):

To install *nodemon*, use the following (if required, use *sudo* to run the installation with root privileges:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

This will install *nodemon* globally on your machine.

Then, in your WebStorm *Run Configuration*, add the following, leaving everything else unchanged:

- Node parameters: `/usr/local/bin/nodemon --exec /usr/local/bin/node`

This will instruct the node interpreter to execute the `nodemon` script using the following command line: `node /usr/local/bin/nodemon --exec /usr/local/bin/node server.js`.

The `--exec` part is important, as the execution will fail with the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodemon server.js
4 Oct 13:56:50 - [nodemon] v0.7.10
4 Oct 13:56:50 - [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
4 Oct 13:56:50 - [nodemon] watching: /Users/foo/test
execvp(): No such file or directory
4 Oct 13:56:50 - [nodemon] starting `node server.js`
4 Oct 13:56:50 - [nodemon] exception in nodemon killing node
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:980:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:771:34)
```

The error seems to be caused by WebStorm not seeing the `node` executable on its path.

The fix for this is to specify the location to the `node` executable using the `--exec /usr/local/bin/node` parameter.

Using these settings, *nodemon* works fine when run from a WebStorm *Run Configuration*.

The same trick might have to be used with some of the tools similar to *nodemon*, e.g. [node-supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor).

Comment: This works for Run Configuration, but not with Debug. Any idea to Debug as well with nodemon in webstorm?

Comment: At least with Webstorm 8 EAP and nodemon 1.0.15 you don't have to specify `--exec` anymore. All I had to do was use `/usr/local/bin/nodemon` in "Node parameters".

Comment: @bernhardw: I can confirm the same

Answer (score 17):

I'm on Windows and for me didn't worked with nodemon (no idea why), but someone from Jetbrains suggested to try with supervisor:

1. I installed supervisor: `npm install supervisor -g`
2. Then find where is `supervisor` installed, for me was in: 
   `C:\Users\AlinC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\supervisor\lib\cli-wrapper.js –no-restart-on error`
3. I went back to Intellij: edit configurations -> node parameters -> and added:
   C:\Users\AlinC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\supervisor\lib\cli-wrapper.js –no-restart-on error

[image: edit configurations]

[image: node parameters]

Comment: To stop on breakpoint you should add this:
`--debug-brk` and complete string is `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\supervisor\lib\cli-wrapper.js no-restart-on error --debug-brk`
Check from jetbrains http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/run-debug-configuration-node-js.html address

Comment: Couldn't get nodemon working on Windows 8 with Webstorm 9, this worked like a charm tho

Comment: Works for me (Webstorm 11 on Windows) but the breakpoints don't work. I tried adding `--debug-brk` but no luck.

Comment: [Start nodemon with `--inspect` flag and then attach a debugger to it](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-and-debugging-node-js.html#nodemon).

Answer (score 17):

For those interested for the solution in Windows 10, here is my configuration. It does not show "Terminate Batch" thing and works perfectly.

[image]

You press debug ONCE and than you can save change files whatever and the server will restart in debug mode. All brakepoints are working perfectly

Comment: this is working answer for debug. I set only node parameters. node parameters as text (change username): c:\users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js --debug=3001

Comment: This didn't work for me. Adding the --debug=3001 parameter crashed nodemon

Comment: Thanks.The basic run is working and also the debug without any problems!This should be TOP answer!

Answer (score 9):

For windows users set:

Node Interpreter: Path of the node.exe i.e. c:\program files\node\node.exe

Node parameter: C:\Users\YOURUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js

Comment: This worked for me! Debugging and break points work perfectly.
Node  version 10.15.1
nodemon version 1.18.10
Webstorm 2018.3.5

Answer (score 5):

You can also make it work with nvm and debugging still works.

Tested with Node.js 8.1.0 and Webstorm 2017.2

First make sure you are on the right version (in my case v8.1.0) and install nodemon globally -

```
nvm use v8.1.0
npm install -g nodemon
```

Then, open Run/Debug configurations and create a new one with the correct node interpreter.

Node parameters should be:

*MAC*

```
/Users/[YOUR_USER]/.nvm/versions/node/v8.1.0/bin/nodemon --inspect=3001
```

*LINUX*

```
/usr/local/nvm/versions/node/v8.1.0/bin/nodemon --inspect=3001
```

Save and debug respponsibally :)

[image: Node.js nodemon webstorm debug]

Answer (score 5):

In case you've installed nodemon like a global library, just set in node parameters:

C:\Users\${yourUser}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js

[image: nodemon in webstorm]

Comment: Works like a charm through nvm and npm 14.7.0

Answer (score 5):

This is the only thing that worked for me:

1. Add a new package.json node run script command:

[image]

2. Create an **NPM CONFIG** (not a node config)
3. Select "start-watch" as the command

[image]

For me this worked for debugging / breakpoints without issues or additional headache.

Comment: Seems if you do this, "break on exception" does not break on exceptions:(

Comment: It worked like a charm for me on MacOS 13.1, node 18. Stops at breakpoints very well.
On the contrary, using Node configuration (as in most top answers) doesn't start.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the configuration that works for me on Windows 7 + WebStorm 8.0.4. If I put nodemon.cmd as the node interpreter I kept getting "Terminate batch job (Y/N)?".

[image: Nodemon + Webstorm on Windows]

Comment: see my answer regarding this question on Windows, I think you were pointing to the wrong nodemon.cmd file

Answer (score 1):

1. Do a npm install nodmemon -g
2. Only change the Path to Node to the nodemon.cmd, in my case (C:\Users\Rohit Taneja\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemon.cmd), you'll also get this path after your installion of nodemon finishes.
3. You're good to go

Answer (score 1):

some of these answers appear to only work for Mac. For Windows, this configuration seems to work (my user name on Windows 7 is denman).

[image]

main.js is the starting point file for my Express application.

Answer (score 1):

Just add new script to `package.json` called nodemon (or choose your own name)

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "nodemon": "nodemon ./bin/www"
}
```

Then go to **Run/Debug Configuration** and add **npm** configuration. Set

- **Command** to "**run**"
- **Script** to "**nodemon**" (name you chose in package.json)

[image: example]

Answer (score 1):

I have a development in mac and as OdkoPP indicates I made it work

```
"scripts": {
"build": "tsc",
"dev": "nodemon src/index.ts --exec ts-node"
},
```

Run/Debug Configurations npm:
[image: Run/Debug Configurations npm]

Answer (score 0):

Per @bernhardw comment, as this was the answer for me -

All is needed is `/usr/local/bin/nodemon` under `node parameters`
Works for run and debug as it restarts upon changes, **but** debugging with breakpoint does not work.

Bonus: add -e for more extension e.g `/usr/local/bin/nodemon -e js,html,jade`

(osx 10.10.5, rubymine 7.1.4)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

npm install -g nodemon

```
1* goto run->Edit Configurations->Press'+' at left corner and choose Node.js

2* Select Node.js and Press '+' 

3* Name as Nodemon, add path in javaScript file: C:\Users\Your_User_Name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\bin\nodemon.js

4* Click Apply and Ok

5* Run the Nodemon
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Script in package.json:  "start": "nodemon --inspect -r babel-register src",

First pic: Run debug and it will start

Second pic: attaching to existing running node 
[image: Settings]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix for an error I was getting...

If you are using a Windows + NodeJS + nodemon.
With an IntelliJ - Run Configuration.

```
ERROR: starting inspector on failed: address already in use
```

When I use nodemon version 1.19.1, I get the error.
When I use nodemon version 1.18.11, it works!

Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

This is how I am running

1. Installed nodemon package

   npm install -g nodemon    # OR using yarn: yarn global add nodemon
2. From Webstorm terminal, run

   nodemon index.js

This is how it will show running in terminal

[image]