# Combining WebStorm 7 Live Edit with Nodemon

Tags: webstorm, nodemon, liveedit

I was able to get live edit working following these instructions:
[running-and-debugging-node-js](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/running-and-debugging-node-js.html)

And I was able to get nodemon running following this post:
[How can I run nodemon from within WebStorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180702/how-can-i-run-nodemon-from-within-webstorm)

However, I am unable to combine the two configurations to get live edit working with nodemon...

If I add nodemon parameters to my live edit config it stops working

ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Works fine for me (WebStorm 7.0.1). here is my nodemon run configuration (I'm on Windows 7):

```
**Configuration tab**

Working directory: my project dir

JavaScript file: ~\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\nodemon.js

Application parameters: app.js

**Browser/LiveEdit tab**

'After launch' checked

'with javascript debugger' checked

http://localhost:3000/index.html
```

Whe I run this configuration in debugger, all changes made to html/css (served using connect.static) are 'live'

If similar configuration doesn't work for you, can you provide a sample project that shows up your problem?

Comment: hmm.. I'm still new to WebStorm, but I was able to get it working by launching each debugging session separately.  I created a config for Nodemon, launch the session, and then create a config for Live-Edit and launched that as well.  Now if I make a change to a js file nodemon will restart, and editing my jade files is live.  Pretty awesome !

Comment: @Dustin, You shouldn't have to create new debugging sessions each time you want the live to update.  I'm running nodemon in Webstorm 10.0.3.  What happens for me is I go to my jade template, change some of the markup, and my existing debug session refreshes the browser automatically.  I make the change then I toggle back to Chrome and it refreshes itself!  That's the experience you should be seeing.

Comment: @Dustin, make sure you have added nodemon to your package.json definintion.  If you didn't install nodemon with the --save option which would have added that entry to your package.json for you, you'll need to manually add that to your dev dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Do you have nodemon added to your package.json?

```
"devDependencies": {
  "nodemon": "~1.3.7"
},
```

or did you install nodemon with the --dev flag which would have added that for you?  e.g. `install nodemon --dev`