# Use nodemon or supervisor to reload only the files without restart all the server - WebStorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm, nodemon, node-supervisor

I just took a look to this tutorial: [How can I run nodemon from within WebStorm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180702/how-can-i-run-nodemon-from-within-webstorm)

I'm wondering how reload only the files updated and don't restart the entire server instance.
I'm wondering also if it's possible to don't break a debug breakpoint, because for the moment the entire server is restarted and if I'm following instruction step by step using the debogguer, I lost the track.

By the way, there are my ways to use them with webstorm, it's particularly tricky with supervisor. Because it needs to get the app.js and everything as parameters.

Supervisor: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByzbHcAxmCyvTGdHOWJSTTYzNWs/edit

Nodemon: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByzbHcAxmCyvdVQ3azFhSlV0dEU/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use modules like [hotswap](https://github.com/rlidwka/node-hotswap) to reload files when they change.

It can cause memory leaks and other stuff, but it's working fine for development.

Comment: I will take a look, but I thought that was also possibl with nodemon and supervisor. (I don't really want to use too many tools that basicaly do the same stuff)

Comment: nodemon and supervisor are designed to restart application completely, it's not the same stuff

Comment: I thought they could do both. My bad. Thx.