# How do you set up file watcher in Webstorm to restart Node.js?

Tags: node.js, webstorm, file-watcher

What I am trying to achieve is to trigger same behavior as Menu option Run > Run 'server.js'

[image: file watcher]

Comment: I haven't used webstorm but have you used nodemon? Maybe you can pass nodemon to webstorm so that it restarts the app on change

Comment: Thanks for hint @Filype  
Here http://stackoverflow.com/a/21034724/1632404 I found solution that works for me.

Comment: Here the debugger restart after the code changes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52463378/7350853

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to integrate webstorm with nodemon instead of the main node program. Basically nodemon is in charge of restarting your application and not webstorm.

Answer (score 4):

Please try using Live Edit here - see http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/08/live-edit-updates-in-webstorm-9/. It allows re-starting node.js application on changing the code

Comment: Looks like Live Edit do not work with API type project as I do not have startup page.