# Having nodemon and debugging both working in a WebStorm run configuration

Tags: node.js, debugging, babeljs, koa, nodemon

This is a problem I have never really been able to sort and have come across a few times so I thought I'd ask on here to see if there is a solution.

I am currently building a NodeJS(koa) application using babel to transpile the ES6 code. I have setup a run configuration which looks like this:

[image]

This setups a debug configuration in order for me to debug my ES6 code.
This works great but I want the debugger to be able to run using nodemon so that when i make changes to the code, the run configuration restarts the server but keeps the debugging functionality. Is this possible from a run configuration or does it have to be done from the command line? At the moment I can only run the debugger OR nodemon... not both at the same time. 
Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I completely understood, but does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22588800/4033215) help?

Comment: That is the problem I am having yes. The issue being that when I add 'nodemon' to the run configuration node parameters the server watches for changes fine but breakpoints do not work.